# Using behavior in qml ui form

Tags: qml, qtquick-designer

is there a way to use behavior from outside the item ? (QtQuick designer doesn't support behavior).

say I have a rectangle defined in From.ui.qml with then id rec, in the file Form.qml I want to assign a behavior on x property of rec, how can I do it.?

Comment: You expose the `x` property of `rec` in the root element of the `From.ui.qml`. Then you can define a behavior on this exposed property.

Comment: Okey but it will be exposed as a public property as well ??

Comment: Aye. That is true.

Comment: your solution do the job, but exposing it as a public property sounds bad a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Step: Expose the object with the property you want to change

[image]

This will create a `property alias` in the `ui.qml`-file.

*// NewFormular.ui.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    property alias rectangle1: rectangle1

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle1
        x: 77
        y: 69
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "#ffffff"
    }
}
```

2. Step: Add the Behavior

*//New.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.4

NewFormular {
    Behavior on rectangle1.x {
        NumberAnimation { duration: 500 }
    }

    Timer {
        running: true
        interval: 1000
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: rectangle1.x = (rectangle1.x + 500) % 600
    }
}
```

3. Step: Instantiate it in your `main.qml`

*//main.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true
    color: 'grey'
    New {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

If you want to hide it again, you can wrap it in a `Item` again:

*//New.qml v2*

```
import QtQuick 2.4
Item {
    id: root
    NewFormular {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Behavior on rectangle1.x {
            NumberAnimation { duration: 500 }
        }

        Timer {
            running: true
            interval: 1000
            repeat: true
            onTriggered: rectangle1.x = (rectangle1.x + 500) % 600
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okey I see, you suggest that I create a normal QtQuick designer item that wrap it in another Item and expose what I want a properties.

Comment: Yes, as the [documentatio](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-ui-forms.html) states, that `Behavior`s are not supported in `ui.qml`-files, the only option is, to add them externally - for which you need to expose the properties at least in the `ui.qml`-file.

Comment: Ok, It's the only solution, I will stick to it. Thank you very much for your help